# Parameters on php files run via cron

Tags: php

I have a php file that needs to be run on a cronjob and the top of it has the following

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
```

i know the first part tells the server to interpret the file with php cause its not being run through the webserver, but what is the -q for?

Also, are there other parameters? If so, where can i read more about them.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`-q` refers to *quiet mode* where header information isn't displayed.  This is now on by default but `-q` is still supported for backward compatability.

```
Usage: php [options] [-f] <file> [--] [args...]
       php [options] -r <code> [--] [args...]
       php [options] [-B <begin_code>] -R <code> [-E <end_code>] [--] [args...]
       php [options] [-B <begin_code>] -F <file> [-E <end_code>] [--] [args...]
       php [options] -- [args...]
       php [options] -a

  -a               Run as interactive shell
  -c <path>|<file> Look for php.ini file in this directory
  -n               No php.ini file will be used
  -d foo[=bar]     Define INI entry foo with value 'bar'
  -e               Generate extended information for debugger/profiler
  -f <file>        Parse and execute <file>.
  -h               This help
  -i               PHP information
  -l               Syntax check only (lint)
  -m               Show compiled in modules
  -r <code>        Run PHP <code> without using script tags <?..?>
  -B <begin_code>  Run PHP <begin_code> before processing input lines
  -R <code>        Run PHP <code> for every input line
  -F <file>        Parse and execute <file> for every input line
  -E <end_code>    Run PHP <end_code> after processing all input lines
  -H               Hide any passed arguments from external tools.
  -s               Display colour syntax highlighted source.
  -v               Version number
  -w               Display source with stripped comments and whitespace.
  -z <file>        Load Zend extension <file>.

  args...          Arguments passed to script. Use -- args when first argument
                   starts with - or script is read from stdin

  --ini            Show configuration file names

  --rf <name>      Show information about function <name>.
  --rc <name>      Show information about class <name>.
  --re <name>      Show information about extension <name>.
  --ri <name>      Show configuration for extension <name>.
```

`php -l` is the one I use the most.  It's nice, when editing, to be able to run a quick syntax check on a file (in vim, `:! php -l %`)

Answer (score 4):

The -q is the command line option for quite mode. The [PHP Site](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php) has explanations of other command line options (Part way down the page), but as -q is now default it isn't mentioned in the list.

From that page:

> CLI is started up in quiet mode by
>   default, though the -q  and
>   --no-header switches are kept for compatibility so that you can use
>   older CGI scripts.

Answer (score 0):

```
user@ubuntu:~$ php --help
Usage: php [options] [-f] <file> [--] [args...]
       php [options] -r <code> [--] [args...]
       php [options] [-B <begin_code>] -R <code> [-E <end_code>] [--] [args...]
       php [options] [-B <begin_code>] -F <file> [-E <end_code>] [--] [args...]
       php [options] -- [args...]
       php [options] -a

  -a               Run as interactive shell
  -c <path>|<file> Look for php.ini file in this directory
  -n               No php.ini file will be used
  -d foo[=bar]     Define INI entry foo with value 'bar'
  -e               Generate extended information for debugger/profiler
  -f <file>        Parse and execute <file>.
  -h               This help
  -i               PHP information
  -l               Syntax check only (lint)
  -m               Show compiled in modules
  -r <code>        Run PHP <code> without using script tags <?..?>
  -B <begin_code>  Run PHP <begin_code> before processing input lines
  -R <code>        Run PHP <code> for every input line
  -F <file>        Parse and execute <file> for every input line
  -E <end_code>    Run PHP <end_code> after processing all input lines
  -H               Hide any passed arguments from external tools.
  -s               Display colour syntax highlighted source.
  -v               Version number
  -w               Display source with stripped comments and whitespace.
  -z <file>        Load Zend extension <file>.

  args...          Arguments passed to script. Use -- args when first argument
                   starts with - or script is read from stdin

  --ini            Show configuration file names

  --rf <name>      Show information about function <name>.
  --rc <name>      Show information about class <name>.
  --re <name>      Show information about extension <name>.
  --ri <name>      Show configuration for extension <name>.
```

Answer (score 0):

Most Unix-like operating systems ship with [manpages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page) (manual pages) which contain documentation about commands.

By calling

```
man php
```

in a terminal, the manpage for php will be displayed in that terminal. It contains the various different options that are available. Here's a html version of the output:
http://linux.die.net/man/1/php

Answer (score -1):

Where is some information [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php), but it doesn't list the -q parameter. But, that page also lists examples on how to take parameters from the command line.